# MailChimp Integration imports First Name, but not Last Name

Tags: import

CiviCRM 4.4.14 (Drupal)

I am trying to use the MailChimp integration extension but on importing a list from MailChimp, only the first name is imported. I've gone through all the settings but cannot find a way to get last name too.

Answer (score 3):

The extension looks for specific MailChimp merge token names (FNAME, LNAME, and EMAIL). You can check it out in the function CRM_Mailchimp_Utils::updateContactDetails() if you want to see the guts of what it is doing. If your merge tokens are different, I think your options would be:

- update your tokens on the MC side
- hack the extension to hard-code your own token names instead of the default ones
- improve the extension by creating some kind of field mapping!
- create your own extension to override the functions that affect merge tokens